# Different uitableview cell height for iPhone and iPad devices using adaptive layout

Tags: ios, swift, storyboard

I am designing universal app for multiple devices. I want different uitableviewcell height for these devices only using storyboard and constraints or you can say I want to do so using adaptive layout or size classes. I have searched alot but could not find any solution. Please guide me in this regard.

Comment: what you have tried yet....???

Comment: I have made a cell using storyboard and its height is 100. When I run the program using iPhone device, it is showing height that is set for iPad i.e 100. I want its height 50 for iPhone while 100 for iPad. I do not want to do it using programming.

Comment: then you can use two storyboard, one for iPhone and second for iPad.

Comment: I am using xcode 8  and I think this is not a good approach to use 2 storyboards.

Answer (score 3):

you could implement the height for cell function and in it check

```
 override func tableView(tableView: UITableView!, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath!) -> CGFloat {

 if (UIDevice.current.userInterfaceIdiom == UIUserInterfaceIdiom.pad)   
  {
    // Ipad
     return 100;
  }
 else 
  {
   // Iphone
     return 50;
  }
}
```

Comment: Dear Khaled, I know how to do it using code. But i want to know is there anything to solve this issue only using storyboard. Actually i am learning autolayout and size classes so it want to do it visually only. And some idiot is down voting me on asking question. . . .:(

Comment: actually yes you can solve it using autolayout please follow this tutorial hope it would be a great help for you

http://candycode.io/automatically-resizing-uitableviewcells-with-dynamic-text-height-using-auto-layout/

https://www.raywenderlich.com/129059/self-sizing-table-view-cells